# Accessing object in one class from another class in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, connection-string

Here is my database connection class.I want to access 'oracleCommand' object reference from another class.

```
public class DBConnection
        { 
            //public OracleCommand oracleCommand;
            public string cmd = "";
            public void makeConnection()
            {
                //Opening connection
                string connectionString = "XXXX";
                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                con.Open();
                OracleCommand oracleCommand = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd = oracleCommand.CommandText;
                //Clossing resources
                con.Close();
                oracleCommand.Dispose();
            }
```

Then I want to execute the following query.

```
dbConnection.cmd = "SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) FROM EmployeeTable WHERE STATUS='Pending'";
                OracleDataReader Reader = dbConnection.oracleCommand.ExecuteReader();
                Reader.Read();
```

But 'dbConnection.oracleCommand.ExecuteReader()' does not hit when debugging. Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You´re hiding the member `oracleCommand` by a variable with the same name that exists within the `makeConnection`-method. Omit the declaration in your method:

```
public class DBConnection
{ 
    public OracleCommand oracleCommand;
    public string cmd = "";
    public void makeConnection()
    {
        //Opening connection
        string connectionString = "XXXX";
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        con.Open();
        this.oracleCommand = con.CreateCommand(); // here
        cmd = oracleCommand.CommandText;
        //Clossing resources
        con.Close();
        oracleCommand.Dispose();
    }
```

However that won´t help you much as you can´t do anything with the command, because yo dispose it once `makeConnection` has run.

Furthermore it´s a bad idea to even *expose* a command to the outside. You should instead expose the connection and create a new command for every statement to be executed on the db:

```
public class DBConnection
{ 
    public OracleConnection { get; private set; }
    public string cmd = "";
    public void makeConnection()
    {
        //Opening connection
        string connectionString = "XXXX";
        this.Connection = new OracleConnection();
        this.Connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        con.Open();
    }
```

Now create a second method that executes your query and returns its results:

```
public int CountPendingElements()
{
    using(var cmd = this.Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) FROM EmployeeTable WHERE STATUS='Pending'";
        OracleDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Reader.Read();
        return reader.GetInt32(0);
    }
}
```

The `using`-statement ensures that even in case of an exception within the code-block the command is disposed.

As an aside your class should implement `IDisposable` to dispose its underlying connection when you´re done with it.

Comment: Actually what I want is passing value of 'oracleCommand ' to the other class

Comment: See my first code-example. However as I already mentioned a command is just *one single command*. You should re-create it upon every sql-statement you want to execute. Apart from this you shouldn´t dispose it within your `makeConnection`-method, as you can´t use it in any way.

Comment: @RMD With _"passing value of 'oracleCommand ' "_ you mean the _result_ that is returned through the reader?

Comment: @RMD I´ve updated my answer to return the result of your query.